# Xamarin iOS project cannot find main project

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm not able to debug my app. When I run it, all I get is a blank screen and the following application output. It says it is not able to find the main project. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Launched application 'com.DragonInvestor.Mobile' on 'iPhone' with pid 1064
2021-01-15 12:07:57.581 DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS[1064:552030] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 7
2021-01-15 12:07:57.583 DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS[1064:552030] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'
2021-01-15 12:07:57.583 DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS[1064:552003] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]

2021-01-15 12:07:58.172 DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS[1064:552003] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'DragonInvestor.Mobile' (culture: '')

Thread started: #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.SkiaSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/WebP.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.Input.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.ConversationalUI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Plugin.Media.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Firebase.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Firebase.Installations.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Firebase.InstanceID.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Firebase.CloudMessaging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/SteepleMate.Model.Standard20.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.Zip.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.Documents.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.Documents.Fixed.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.PdfViewer.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Plugin.Fingerprint.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Reactive.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/LiteDB.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Firebase.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/Telerik.XamarinForms.ImageEditor.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/FFImageLoading.Transformations.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/DragonInvestor.Mobile.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.IO.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/System.Threading.dll [External]
Thread started: #3
Thread started: #4
Thread started: #5
Thread started: #6
Thread started: #7
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF88D84E-F31A-4EDB-80B9-C70B5DCCB9BC/DragonInvestor.Mobile.iOS.app/OpenTK-1.0.dll [External]
Thread started: #8
Thread finished: #5
```

Comment: Have you connected your xamarin development environment to an actual mac for debugging? Last time I used xamarin in visual studio I needed to connect to a 'Host-PC' (a mac) for debugging. It wasn't as easy as running the android emulator.

Comment: Thanks Ann; I should have been more clear.  I am running this on my mac using the latest Visual Studio.